# Proof that absolute integrability does not imply square integrability

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, absolute-convergence

I'm trying to prove that absolute integrability does not imply square integrability. I am able find a counterexample, for example $|x|^{-1/2} / (1+x^2)$, but I would like to find the conditions under which the implication does not hold.

I tried using Cauchy-Schwarz but that didn't get me anywhere. What would be a good starting point?

Comment: What is "the general case"? A single counterexample is enough to prove the nonimplication.

Comment: @Travis I think he want a condition for the functions which are absolutely integrable but not square integrable.

Comment: @Travis thanks, edited to reflect this clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to look into what is refered as [$L_p$ norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) (and Banach spaces), as these criteria involve different norms (e.g absolute value, square norm and so on). So the criteria are related to the norm used, especialy check [Relations between p-norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Relations_between_p-norms)

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by ||x||p+a ≤ ||x||p. That seems to imply that an absolutely integrable function will always be square integrable, with a solution smaller than for the absolute integration.

Comment: the wikipedia article in that case, talks about finite vector spaces, not banach spaces (which include functions), the cauchy-swartz ineq can be seen in a unified framework in normed spaces

Comment: I want to accept this answer because it points in the right direction, but I'm afraid it brings me back to Cauchy-Schwartz, which was my unsuccessful starting point. I have near zero formal math background so a little more detail would be appreciated (I'm not looking for the actual proof/conditions).

Comment: if the answer does not help enough is not necessary to accept. unfortunately i cannot provide more info as i need to look into this subject myself, although i think if any such conditions are to be found this is the place to look

Comment: one point could be to study the counter-example already found but from a more general normed perspective, how it behaves under different norms

Answer (score 0):

x(t) =       1/√t     for 0 < t ≤ 1
x(t) =       0        elsewhere

Link----->[MIT Page](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-011-introduction-to-communication-control-and-signal-processing-spring-2010/readings/MIT6_011S10_notes.pdf)